# Changing app.config for Entity Framework and log4net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, log4net

I'm using Entity Framework along with log4net in my Console Application.  Here's what my app.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:\\Temp\\Logs\\"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyMMdd_HHmm'.log'" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
  <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %logger [%thread] (Line :%line) %level - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CAPDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CAPDB.csdl|res://*/CAPDB.ssdl|res://*/CAPDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=caServer;initial catalog=CAPDB;persist security info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="USPDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/USPDB.csdl|res://*/USPDB.ssdl|res://*/USPDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=UsServer;initial catalog=USPDB;persist security info=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I get a "ConfigErrorsException was unhandled" error.  It's pointing to my CAPDBEntities that I've set up.  What do I have to change to have both EF & log4net working using the same app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.  I downloaded Entity Framework from Nuget & recreated App.config.  It worked after that.